# Misunderstanding while querying Contacts

Tags: java, android, contactscontract

I have a single piece of code, which supposed to output all numbers in Contacts.
However, it also outputs name of contact:

```
import ... ;    
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
        private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
            int[] toViews = { android.R.id.text1 }; 
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // textView
                    cursor, // cursor
                    fromColumns, 
                    toViews,
                    0 );
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
}
```

I am querying only ONE column `CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` however outputs goes this way:
**12345**
*Sarah*
**34189**
*Bill*
**41279**
*Johnny*
...
Am i missing something ?